# Is there a way to auto-add to a table range already used for data validation?

Tags: excel

I understand how I can create a lookup range of values via data validation for a column of cells.

What I want to do is provide the ability in that column of cells to enter a value not in the lookup range of values, have Excel accept that value and automatically add it to the range of values in the look up.

Example:

In worksheet I call "application cost" I have two columns, "Application", and "cost" For application, ihave direct data validation and choose from a range on another worksheet called "Applications" that contains columns called "applications" and "description", It currently has these values:

```
application A, a cool app
application B, an awful app
```

In the worksheet "Application cost" I want a person to choose from a pull-down for the application column and choose from the "Applications worksheet. After setting up data validation appropriately, this worksheet allows me to choose from application A or application B. I know how to do this.

The behavior I want in the worksheet "Application cost" is to be able to type in a new app, "application C" and it will allow this and automatically add it to the range of look ups in the applications worksheet so that it now has the following for it's look up.

application A, a cool app
application B, an awful app
application C

I've tried looking at options in data validation but I'm unable to find anything that helps that second step.

Perhaps I have to accomplish this via some way other than data validation.

Comment: Do you have the UNIQUE function available?

Comment: Could you provide a sentence or two to elaborate the value of UNIQUE in this question?

Comment: You can use the UNIQUE function to create a unique list of the entries currently in the column, which will update to include any newly added entries.